# Resize divs of class to largest

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have divs inside of table cells, and the goal is to get the table cells of equal height across each row on android devices where some of the content wraps. With much trial and error, the only way I can see to do this is to encapsulate td contents inside of divs, then resize each div to the height of the tallest instance. Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var tInt = 0;
$('.resizeDiv').each(function () {
    d = this.offsetHeight;
    if (d > tInt) { d = tInt; }
});
$('.resizeDiv').each(function () {
    this.css('height', d + 'px');
    this.css('min-height', d + 'px');
    this.css('display', 'block');
});
```

There are many td tags generated server-side, here is a standard one:

```
<td><div class='menuItemS resizeDiv'>8858600448</div></td>
```

The menuItemS is just generic styling (background gradient), and there is no CSS applied to the resizeDiv class. The code above is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want it by height or width?

Comment: Height. Currently, if a td (e.g., the middle column) has data that wraps into two lines, the cell's height is increased. When the middle cell's height is increased, the other column height remain the same (this reveals the background color of the table). I would like all columns in the row to be the same height

Comment: look the answer below and see if you find it useful, if not don't, then guide me for  what you want?

Comment: @divy3993: The solution you provided is nice, but it does not work. In jFiddle, try adding 'asdf' inside the middle td and you'll see just what I'm dealing with. Thanks though

Comment: Check the updated answer now, if still any problem feel free to ask

Comment: Your code works, and mine does not - that means that whatever it is can only be on me. Time to go trapsing through code...kudos to you, and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for:

I have accomplish by **table-layout:fixed;** property of CSS.

[WORKING : DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v06w8ea8/5/) : **UPDATED**

**CSS**

```
html, body
{
    margin:0%;
    width:100%;
}

table
{
    margin:1% 0%;
    width:98%;
    background:#333;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px 0px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.box
{
    margin:0;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%; /*Changed from auto to 100% */
    width:100%;
    background:#ddd;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<center>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>        
        <div class="box">
            Hello <br /> Hey There... <br /> How you doing?
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: Just left to alter height:100%;